# right after it says Ganache is installed, it says the command not found - any suggestions please

Tags: macos, installation, command, truffle, ganache

so in third line it tells me I have Ganache v7.4.3 installed, then when confirming installation/version, it tells me command not found. Does this mean it isn't installed? Or installed wrong? Super appreciate any advise or suggestions, please!

h1-231@H1-231noMacBook-Air ~ % truffle version
Truffle v5.6.0 (core: 5.6.0)
Ganache v7.4.3
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v18.10.0
Web3.js v1.7.4
h1-231@H1-231noMacBook-Air ~ % ganache version
zsh: command not found: ganache

Answer (score 0):

You ran `truffle version`, which displays the Truffle version and some key dependencies that Truffle uses, one of which is Ganache. However, this does *not* mean you have Ganache installed *globally*. Currently, Truffle can use Ganache because it is a dependency of Truffle, but you cannot use Ganache outside of that context.

Try running `npm i -g ganache` to install Ganache globally.